# ( was unexpected at this time in a FOR loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

So Im having this problem where my batch for loop doesnt work, I havent found any solutions for this. It keeps saying "( was unexpected at this time". Could anyone help please?

```
for /F %%G IN ('TYPE info.txt') DO (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set /a div=%cnt% %% 2
    if %div% == 0 {
        set ord=%%G
        echo %ord%
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This only works if you use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), otherwise all your variables will only be evaluated once.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set cnt=0
for /F %%G IN ('TYPE info.txt') DO (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set /a div=!cnt! %% 2
    if !div!==0  (
     set ord=%%G 
     echo !ord!
     )
)
```

Or you could use labels instead.

```
for /F %%G IN ('TYPE info.txt') DO call :line %%G
goto :EOF

:line
set /a cnt+=1
set /a div=%cnt% %% 2
if "%div%"=="0" call :div0 %1
goto :EOF

:div0
set ord=%1
echo %ord%
goto :EOF
```

Comment: rene, your upper code is flawed as delayed expansion is required and your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @foxidrive Thanks, at first glance the output looked ok too me...fixed now.